# Is there an easy way to update all (most) extensions at once?

Tags: updates, visual-studio-2015

So I didn't use Visual Studio for a while and noticed there are quite a few updated components/extensions:

[image: Extensions and Updates window showing available product updates.]

While updating one or two extensions is rather quick, this feels very tedious with multiple updates:

- I have to open Visual Studio and the dialog window, pick the extension and click on **Update**.
- This downloads and starts some installer. Usually I have to close Visual Studio to ensure I don't have to reboot before installing the next component.
- So to update the next component, I have to start from the first step once more.

Is there really no way to do some "Update all" or at least a convenient "Download all" option?

I'm aware that this is probably something that won't work for third party downloads/installers, but even the Microsoft ones using the original Visual Studio setup are installed one by one only.

Downloading the updates by looking up homepages etc. is obviously not really an option - I could just go with the tedious way instead.

Comment: That's what I fear as well, but maybe there's something we're missing.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't an in-built way to do this, there is an extension capable of auto updating your extensions when a new version is released. Please check [Visual Studio Auto Updater](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/14973bbb-8e00-4cab-a8b4-415a38d78615).

Comment: Neat, unfortunately it's incompatible with version 2015.

Comment: i wonder if it would install and work if you were to change <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[12.0]" /> property in extension.vsixmanifest file. Can't try it myself as i don't have VS2015 installed.

Comment: No, while a good idea it won't magically change/update dependencies as well.